# Why is the raycaster objects property not working in A-Frame?

Tags: aframe

I am on A-Frame v0.3.0. I am trying to use the `raycaster` component's `objects` along with the `cursor` component to select which entities it should raycast against. But the `objects` property is not working.

```
<a-box class="box"></a-box>
<a-entity cursor raycaster="objects: .box"></a-entity>
```

- https://aframe.io/docs/0.3.0/components/raycaster.html#whitelisting-entities-to-test-for-intersection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently a bug where the `cursor` component is not waiting for the `raycaster` component to initialize even thought it set it as a dependency.

https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/1841

The workaround is to swap the order in which they are defined in HTML, `raycaster` first:

```
<a-box class="box"></a-box>
<a-entity raycaster="objects: .box" cursor></a-entity>
```